# Want to know the parameters to execute listen with REST API

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I intended to specify minimum parameters to do Firestore listen API https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/firestore/v1beta1/projects.databases/listen , but Response was 400 Invalid.

What is missing from my request?

POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/metal-tile-dev1/databases/(default)/documents:listen

```
{
 "addTarget": {
  "once": false,
  "query": {
   "structuredQuery": {
    "from": [
     {
      "collectionId": "cities"
     }
    ]
   }
  },
  "readTime": "2017-09-06T03:32:02.951319Z"
 }
}
```

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firestore/firestore/v1beta1/firestore.projects.databases.documents.listen?database=projects%252Fmetal-tile-dev1%252Fdatabases%252F(default)&_h=8&resource=%257B%250A++%2522addTarget%2522%253A+%250A++%257B%250A++++%2522once%2522%253A+false%252C%250A++++%2522query%2522%253A+%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522structuredQuery%2522%253A+%250A++++++%257B%250A++++++++%2522from%2522%253A+%250A++++++++%255B%250A++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++%2522collectionId%2522%253A+%2522cities%2522%250A++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++%255D%250A++++++%257D%250A++++%257D%252C%250A++++%2522readTime%2522%253A+%25222017-09-06T03%253A32%253A02.951319Z%2522%250A++%257D%250A%257D&

Comment: I am a google group and now I was told that this function does not work. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-firestore-discuss

Comment: Forum link was wrong https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/REST$20API$20listen%7Csort:date/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/kP8-syZ4c3g/y1y1x4DIAgAJ